# Expectation Proof

Tags: probability

Prove: $ \mathbf E(X \ln(X)) \ge \mathbf EX \ln (\mathbf EX) $

I've tried to rearrange this to:

$ \mathbf E \ln X^X \ge \ln( \mathbf EX^ {\mathbf EX})$

And tried to use Jensen's inequality but letting the function $g(x) = x^x$

But it didn't really work, can someone give me a push in the right direction?

Comment: Why does it not work?

Comment: Apply Jensen's inequality with $f(x)= x\ln x$

Comment: Seems like you're done basically

Comment: Ahh so obvious now I don't know what I was thinking..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Community wiki answer so the question can be marked as answered:

As Petite Etincelle suggested in a comment, you can apply Jensen's inequality to the convex function $f(x)=x\ln x$ to obtain $\mathbb E(f(X))=\mathbb E(X\ln X)\ge\mathbb E(X)\ln(\mathbb E(X))=f(\mathbb E(X))$.